# A question about upper Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

Let's suppose $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ a bounded function. I need to show that $\left|\int_{a}^{\overline{b}} f(x) \: dx\right| \leq \int_{a}^{\overline{b}} |f(x)| \: dx$, where all the integrals are Upper Riemann Integrals.

I've tried to get started by the definition of $f$ being bounded; There exists $M>0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq 0$. I don't see where this can actualy help me proving what I intend to.

I know, by integral properties, that $\left|\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \: dx\right| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)| \: dx$, where all the integrals are Riemann Integrals. So maybe that fact can help me I just don't see how.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Show the inequality for the upper Riemann sum of some fixed partition and then conclude by taking the supremum over all partitions.

Comment: A nice trick here is to write  $$f(x) = f_+(x) - f_-(x)$$ where $$f_+(x) = \max\{f(x), 0\}\\f_-(x) = \max\{0, -f(x)\}$$ Then $|f(x)| = f_+(x) + f_-(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, Upper Riemann Integrals only defined for bounded functions, that's why we need to assume that.
now, in this answer i will denote by $U(f)$ the upper riemann integral of $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$ and by $U(f,\Pi)$ the upper darboux sum of $f$ with partition $\Pi$ on the interval $[a,b]$.

I will start the proof with two helpful claims:

1. if $f$ is bounded, non negative function on $[a,b]$, then $U(f)\geq0$
2. if $f,g$ are bounded functions on $[a,b]$, then $U(f+g)\leq U(f)+U(g)$

**Proof Of Claim 1**

Suppose that $\Pi=\{a=x_0<x_1\cdots<x_n-1<x_n=b\}$ is a partition of the interval $[a,b]$, we will denote $M_i=\sup_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)$. by the assumption that $f$ is non negative we can conclude that $M_i\geq0$, from that we get $U(f,\Pi)=\sum_{k=1}^nM_i\cdot|x_i-x_{i-1}|\geq0$, after taking the infimum over all the partitions we will conclude that $U(f)=\inf_\Pi U(f,\Pi)\geq0$ as wanted.

**Proof Of Claim 2**

Suppose that $\Pi=\{a=x_0<x_1\cdots<x_n-1<x_n=b\}$ is a partition of the interval $[a,b]$. Than
$$\begin{align}
U(f+g,\Pi)=&\sum_{k=1}^n\sup_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}(f+g)\cdot|x_i-x_{i-1}|\\
\leq& \sum_{k=1}^n\sup_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}f\cdot|x_i-x_{i-1}|+\sum_{k=1}^n\sup_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}g\cdot|x_i-x_{i-1}|\\
=&U(f,\Pi)+U(g,\Pi)
\end{align}$$
Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since the upper integral is the infimum of the upper sums, there are
partitions Q, R such that
$$U(f,Q)<U(f)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2},\hspace{1cm}U(f,R)<U(f)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
and if P is a common refinement of Q and R, then
$$U(f,P)<U(f)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2},\hspace{1cm}U(f,P)<U(f)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
It follows that
$$U(f+g)\leq U(f+g,P)\leq U(f,P)+U(g,P)\leq U(f)+U(g)+\varepsilon$$
Since this inequality holds for arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$, we must have $U(f+g)\leq U(f)+U(g)$ as we wanted.

now let's go back to the original question. suppose $g$ is a function defined by $g(x)=f(x)+|f(x)|$. So $g$ is non negative, bounded function, thus $0\leq U(g)=U(f+|f|)\leq U(f)+U(|f|)$, It follows that $-U(|f|)\leq U(f)$.

Now suppose that $\Pi=\{a=x_0<x_1\cdots<x_n-1<x_n=b\}$ is a partition of the interval $[a,b]$ S.T $U(|f|,\Pi)<U(|f|)+\varepsilon$. It follows
$$U(f)\leq U(f,\Pi)=\sum_{k=1}^n\sup_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}f\cdot|x_i-x_{i-1}|\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\sup_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}|f|\cdot|x_i-x_{i-1}|=U(|f|,\Pi)<U(|f|)+\varepsilon$$
Since this inequality holds for arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$, we must have $U(f)\leq U(|f|)$. from $-U(|f|)\leq U(f)\leq U(|f|)$ it follows that $|U(f)|\leq U(|f|)$